# flightplan script failing when it tries to run "npm install" on remote machine

Tags: node.js

My flightplan script looks something like:

```
// run commands on remote hosts (destinations)
plan.remote(function(remote) {
  remote.log('Copy to remote host in folder: ' + tmpDir);
  remote.sudo('cp -R /tmp/' + tmpDir + ' ~', {user: username});

  remote.log('Delete temporary local directory');
  remote.rm('-rf /tmp/' + tmpDir);
  remote.log('Install dependencies');
  remote.exec('cd ' + tmpDir);
  remote.sudo('npm --production install', {user: username});
  remote.log('Reload application');
  remote.sudo('ln -snf ~/' + tmpDir + ' ~/' + appName, {user: username});

});
```

The script runs fine until it encounters the "npm --production install" line.

Here are the logs:

```
Copy to remote host in folder: node-app-1452386549897
104.131.12.146 $ sudo -u deploy -i bash -c 'cp -R /tmp/node-app-1452386549897 ~'
104.131.12.146 ● ok
104.131.12.146 Delete temporary local directory
104.131.12.146 $ rm -rf /tmp/node-app-1452386549897
104.131.12.146 ● ok
104.131.12.146 Install dependencies
104.131.12.146 $ cd node-app-1452386549897
104.131.12.146 ● ok
104.131.12.146 $ npm --production install
104.131.12.146 > bash: npm: command not found
failed(127)
```

although it says npm command not found.. the command is very much present on the remote machine

Any idea what could be causing this issue ?

Here's the path on remote machine for the deploy user (which has sudo abilities)

```
/home/deploy/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Here's the path on remote machine for root user:

```
/root/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Here's the PATH to npm:

```
/home/deploy/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin/npm
/root/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin/npm
```

I installed it separately for both root and deploy

Comment: try to call `remote.exec('which npm');` and `remote.sudo('which npm');`.
Probably the `npm` is not in PATH  for root user

Comment: here's the PATH on the remote machine  /home/deploy/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: is `npm` binary in any of directories provided by PATH for both ordinary or root user? I think `npm` is in path for ordinary user, but NOT in PATH for root user. Try simlinking `npm` executable into `/usr/bin`

Comment: root user PATH:  /root/.nvm/v4.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: I have the same issue. I can access `npm` under the root user, however, when `flightplan` runs it, it can not find the binary. It looks like `flightplan` is using different environment or something. Any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution in the issue: [Remote context in unexpected state](https://github.com/pstadler/flightplan/issues/36).

`nvm` is not loaded when shell is executed in non-interactive state by default.

To fix this:

Open your `/root/.bashrc` file and move lines related to `nvm` before the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` expression.

In the end you will get something like this:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution I found is explained here: https://dhampik.com/blog/nodejs-deploy-nvm

I opened the `/home/deploy/.bashrc` file of my `deploy` user and moved the lines that were located at the end of the file after installing nvm:

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/deploy/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

above the lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```